# Can I send bubble video in Telegram-Desktop

Tags: aiogram

Telegram-desktop.
: )
"
Your two parts were merged to make the “body” of the question. Please review and edit to make sure that the question in its entirety makes sense.

When creating questions in the future, there will be only one body field, but for best results remember to include both a description of your problem and what you’ve tried."   :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.